# Wordpress - adding Featured image to custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add a Featured Image to my theme but not for Posts or Pages - I've created a custom type called Properties (its for an estate agent), so how do I enable Featured Image, as it doesn't appear in the sceen options?

Hope someone can help,

```
$property  = new Cuztom_Post_Type( 'Property', array(
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor')
));
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$property  = new Cuztom_Post_Type( 'Property', array(
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
));
```

I appear to have solved my own question - see above

Comment: I like your approach with creating content type - Can you provide link to its documentation? So far I could not find it in docs.

Answer (score 10):

This might help someone,

```
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_post_type_support( 'my_product', 'thumbnail' );    
function create_post_type() {
        register_post_type( 'my_product',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Products' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true
            )
        );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply enable support Post thumbnail for any custom post type with the following line of code in the theme's function.php file.

```
add_post_type_support( 'forum', 'thumbnail' );
```

Note: Here, the `forum` is the post type name.

You can keep this code in the `after_setup_theme` hook.

Answer (score 5):

100% working this code

```
 add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_post_type_support( 'news', 'thumbnail' ); 

function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'news',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'News' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'news' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news'),
            'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-aside',

        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably this would help

```
    function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'sadaf_films',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Films' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Film' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields','thumbnail' ),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use wp cli and scaffold for creating your custom post-type:

`wp scaffold post-type movie ...`

You will find that your generated file (/post-type/movie.php) already has the line, in register_post_type:

`supports: => ['title', 'editor' ]`

And there you can add 'thumbnail':

`supports: => ['title', 'editor', 'thumbnail' ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_post_type_support( 'testimonial', 'thumbnail' );

    function create_posttype() {
     register_post_type( 'testimonial',
        array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Testimonial' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'testimonial' )
                ),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'testimonial'),
                // add category in custom post type
                'taxonomies' => array( 'category'),
            )
        );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```