# how to set featured image to blog Link format type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

We can easily set featured image to standard blog type.
Anybody please suggest me how to set featured image to blog Link format type?

Thank You

Comment: Are you referring to the old Link content type which has been phased-out in WP core for years? Or are you dealing with a custom post type that happens to be labeled Link?

Comment: I am dealing with custom post type

Comment: Well....  see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51897/how-come-featured-image-isnt-showing-up-in-my-custom-post-type), [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32811/set-featured-image-size-for-a-custom-post-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543563/wordpress-adding-featured-image-to-custom-post-type).